# Markerfacecolor in Octave not working?

Tags: plot, octave

I'm trying to plot a collection of points as well as a geometrical shape, which is working fine. However, i wanted bigger dots for the points. The standard octave dot ('.') cannot be resized, apparently.

I thought of using the circle marker instead, which can be resized, but i can't seem to manage to "fill" them.

My code: `plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),"1o","markersize",5,"markerfacecolor","auto",hull(:,1),hull(:,2),"b",roster(:,1),roster(:,2),".0");`

Also, is there a way to make the grid points appear without having to either cope with grid lines, or without having to generate a matrix and plot it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a [bug with octave plot](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Plot-Bug-markerfacecolor-does-not-work-td1673659.html) function that never got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Octave MinGW build. Then I switched to Octave on [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) build, and all checked by me plotting options were working fine. For using plotting you will also need to install XWin X Server to Cygwin.